# Printing out a graph with *

Tags: java, arrays, string, eclipse

I am writing a program that creates a list of x and y values based on user input, then prints out a graph using those values. The only problem I am having is printing out the graph. It prints out the *s, but my program is that it should also print out the numbers. How do i get it to print out just the asterisks?

[the graph should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J46m1.jpg)

[but mine looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsn1o.jpg)

here is the part of my code that deals with the graph:

```
    String starsString = "";

    System.out.println("Graph");

    count = 0;

    yValues[count] = (int)yValues[count];

    while(count < values)
    {

        for(int stars = 0; stars < (int)yValues[count]; stars++)
            {   
                starsString = starsString + (int)yValues[count];
                starsString += "*";
            }

            count++;
            System.out.println(":" +starsString);
            starsString = "";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: just comment `starsString = starsString + (int)yValues[count];` line

Comment: Comment out `yValues[count] = (int)yValues[count];` too.

Comment: If you can use Java 11: `System.out.println("*".repeat((int)values[count]))`

Comment: Beyond that: dont use String + when pulling together strings in a loop. Use a StringBuilder instead, and simply append to that!

Comment: @GhostCat Isn't the compiler able to optimize that anyway?

Comment: @MCEmperor The compiler does replace simply string concats with better solutions, but I rather doubt it is happening here. It might be, and looking into bytecode with javap would tell.

Comment: And just for the record: please do not use images for **textual** content. You should always prefer well formatted text over screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this line is the issue

```
starsString = starsString + (int)yValues[count];
```

Try to remove that line